# Transition matrix exercise

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

*I found this exercise on the internet ( I translated it from French so sorry if it's scuffed. ) I have no idea how to start it, any hint would be appreciated.*

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain with $Q$ being its transition matrix. 
Let $E$ be the set of values the process take and let $x,y\in E$.


Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Q^n(y,x)\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Q^n(x,x)$

**EDIT based on @Michh's answer :**

So I kinda get the general idea now but I didn't get these two transitions in his proof :

1/which conditional expectation property did we use get from line 1 to line 2 here? :
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_y[V_x] &= \mathbb{E}_y[V_x \mathbf{1}_{\{T_x<\infty\}}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_y[ \mathbf{1}_{\{T_x<\infty\}}\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}]].
\end{align}$$

2/Also I dont get how we switched from conditional $y$ to conditional $x$ here $\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}]=\mathbb{E}_x[V_x]$. here I thought Markov's strong property only gives us independence so I get that we can get rid of $\mathcal{F}_t$

Comment: by stochastic matrix you mean transition matrix?

Comment: @user159517 yep I changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $V_x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{X_n = x\}}$ the number of visits of state $x$. Then what you want to prove is
$$ \mathbb{E}_y [V_x] \leq \mathbb{E}_x[V_x].$$

To do this the idea is to apply the strong Markov property at the hitting time of $x$: $$T_x = \inf\{n\geq 1\colon \, X_n = x\}.$$

First notice that on $\{T_x = \infty\}$, we have $V_x = 0$ $\mathbb{P}_y$-a.s. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_y[V_x] &= \mathbb{E}_y[V_x \mathbf{1}_{\{T_x<\infty\}}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_y[ \mathbf{1}_{\{T_x<\infty\}}\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}]].
\end{align}$$
By the strong Markov property, $\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}] = \mathbb{E}_x[V_x].$ This gives
$$\mathbb{E}_y[V_x] = \mathbb{P}_y(T_x<\infty)\mathbb{E}_x[V_x]\leq \mathbb{E}_x[V_x].$$

Comment: What conditional expectation property did we use get from line 1 to line 2 here? : $$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_y[V_x] &= \mathbb{E}_y[V_x \mathbf{1}_{\{T_x<\infty\}}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_y[ \mathbf{1}_{\{T_x<\infty\}}\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}]].
\end{align}$$

Comment: Also I dont get how we switched from conditional $y$ to conditional $x$ here $\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}] = \mathbb{E}_x[V_x].$ here I thought Markov's strong property only gives us independence so I get that we can get rid of $\mathcal{F}_{T_x}$

Comment: @Hijaw To get from line 1 to line 2 I used the definition of the conditional expectation: for any event $A \in \mathcal{F}_{T_x}$, we have $\mathbb{E}_y[\mathbf{1}_A V_x] = \mathbb{E}_y[ \mathbf{1}_A \mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}]]$. Now apply this with $A = \{T_x< \infty\}$ which is $\mathcal{F}_{T_x}$-measurable.

Comment: @Hijaw One way to state the strong Markov property is the following: conditionally on $\mathcal{F}_{T_x}$, the shifted process $(X_{T_x+n}, \, n \geq 0)$ is distributed as $(X_n, \, n \geq 0)$ under $\mathbb{P}_{X_{T_x}}$. But $X_{T_x} = x$ by definition. (In other words, the shifted process is distributed as the initial process started from state $x$).

Comment: Now you can express $V_x$ as a function of the shifted process:
$$V_x = \sum_{n= T_x}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{X_n = x\}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{T_x+n} = x\}},$$
where the RHS is the number of visits of state $x$ by the shifted process.
So $$\mathbb{E}_y[V_x|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}] = \mathbb{E}_y\left[\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{T_x+n} = x\}}\middle|\mathcal{F}_{T_x}\right] = \mathbb{E}_{X_{T_x}}\left[\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{X_n = x\}}\right] = \mathbb{E}_x[V_x].$$ I hope this makes it clearer.